# how to count the records in a query

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to include the rows also in the query instead of doing a different query to count its record, how can i do in mysql

my query looks like this

```
SELECT 
  tblItems.ItemsID,
  tblItems.ItemsTitle,
  tblItems.ItemsManager_ContactID,
  tblItems.EndDate_Scheduled,
  tblItems.ItemsViews_Target,
  tblviews.viewsName,
  tblcontact.FirstName, 
  tblcontact.LastName 
FROM
  tblItems
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tblviews ON (tblItems.Items_viewsID = tblviews.viewsID)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tblcontact ON (tblItems.ItemsManager_ContactID = tblcontact.ContactID)
WHERE (tblItems.ItemsStatusID = 7)
ORDER BY tblItems.EndDate_Scheduled ASC, Items_viewsID ASC
```

i am not sure where i can add count, in SQL we can do but in mYsql i have no idea

Comment: you can count the rows in the code.

Comment: why i had to run a query like `if my query.recordcount` instead of doing in mysql `query ``itself

Comment: you can not do in the same query. For count you have to execute the query again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine the count of the returned rows, you will have to execute the same query again, but instead of selecting the rows, select the count:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM
  tblItems
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tblviews ON (tblItems.Items_viewsID = tblviews.viewsID)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tblcontact ON (tblItems.ItemsManager_ContactID = tblcontact.ContactID)
WHERE (tblItems.ItemsStatusID = 7)
ORDER BY tblItems.EndDate_Scheduled ASC, Items_viewsID ASC
```